# Plus-Minus Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was kind of bored so decided to try and find a way to express $$1±(1/2)∓(1/3)±(1/4)∓(1/5)...$$ as an infinite sum with sigma notation. Failing dismally so far. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\pm\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^n}n$$

Comment: Thank you! That is very useful.

Comment: @Mathime: You’re welcome!

Comment: But the first term in the question is always positive, isn't it?